# ...is a type but is used like a variable

Tags: c#

My idea here is to create a text based adventure game.

I'm trying to use a class in my main class.
While I'm trying to, it gives me the error:

**'MyAdventure.Window' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'**

I'm not sure on how to solve this. I tried creating a new instance of the class but it didn't seem to work.
I am fairly new to this, but could anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Here's the code for my main class (Program.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyAdventure
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("You cannot feel your body. You don't know where you are.\nThe room you're in is dark. You cannot see much.");
        Console.WriteLine("You decide to stand up, and take a look around. You see a door and a window.\nWhich do you check out first?");
        Console.WriteLine("A. Window\nB. Door");

        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        //Window theWindow = new Window();

        if (userInput.StartsWith("A", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            Window();
        }
        else if (userInput.StartsWith("B", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You chose the door.");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

}

And this is the code (so far) for the other class Window.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyAdventure
{
public class Window
{
    static void theWindow()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("You approach the window.");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You want `Window.theWindow()`.

Comment: And also make it public: public static void theWindow()

Comment: You also might want to separate data from code, but I guess that's a different lesson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax to call a static method of a class is the following

```
   if (userInput.StartsWith("A", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
   {
        Window.theWindow();
   }
```

You can't use simply the name of the class, but you should specify the static method to call (one from potentially many methods)

[Calling static methods](http://www.dotnetperls.com/static-method)

Also the method 'theWindow' should be made public otherwise is [private by default inside a class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

> access level for class members and struct members, including nested
>   classes and structs, is private by default

```
public static void theWindow()
{
    Console.WriteLine("You approach the window.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that just now, but it still doesn't work. Now it gives me this: 'MyAdventure.Window.theWindow()' is inaccessible due to its protection level. Do I need to change the myWindow method into something else than static?

Comment: @user1779342 You need to make public the method i.e public static void theWindow()

Comment: Oh I suspected it was something like that. Thank you very much for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

`theWindow()` is a static method. Static members are called like `ClassName.MethodName()`, in your case `Window.theWindow()`

When you did `Window theWindow = new Window();`, you were creating an instance of the `Window` class. Static members cannot be access from instance of a class.

To call that method from an instance, you need to remove the `static` modifier

```
public class Window
{
    public void theWindow()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You approach the window.");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Usage

```
Window w = new Window(); //creating an instance of Window
w.theWindow();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call

```
....
...
if (userInput.StartsWith("A", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
      Window.theWindow();
}
...
...
```